# How can I find a boolean index of a pandas data frame that matches a known subset of the data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with several columns of integers, say they are labeled `A`-`E`. I'm interested in finding the columns where `D < E` based on the relationships between `A`, `B` and `C`. I suspect the relationship is something like `D < E if (A < B) & (B > C)`. My goal is to predict if `D < E` is true given only `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I'm interested also in the theoretical approach and I realize this falls outside of a Python question but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an approach that worked using the `operator` package to iterate over all combinations of inequality relationships. This is the basic approach I used:

```
import itertools
from operator import *

for ineq1, ineq2, ineq3 in itertools.product([lt, le, ge, gt,
                                              lambda a, b: True],
                                              repeat=3):
    mask = ineq1(data.A, data.B) & ineq2(data.B, data.C) & ineq3(data.C, data.A)

    if data[mask].equals(taget_data):
      print([ineq.__name__ for ineq in [ineq1, ineq2, ineq3])
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mask the pandas dataframe with a boolean expression, and chek serveral things to evaluate the relatinship between A, B, C, D and E. My example is based on random number though. But this should give you the direction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]) 

# filtering data on index value 
mask = (df.D < df.E) & (df.A < df.B) & (df.B > df.C) 

print(df)

#    A  B  C  D  E
# 0  1  7  7  9  0
# 1  4  9  3  0  3
# 2  3  4  1  1  6
# 3  2  1  4  3  5
# 4  8  8  2  3  6

print(mask)

# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3    False
# 4    False
# dtype: bool

print(df[mask])

#    A  B  C  D  E
# 1  4  9  3  0  3
# 2  3  4  1  1  6


print(len(df[mask].index))
# 2

print(mask.all())
# False
```

Extra attention on this line:

```
mask = (df.D < df.E) & (df.A < df.B) & (df.B > df.C)
```

where `(df.D < df.E)` is the relation between `D` and `E` and `(df.A < df.B) & (df.B > df.C)` is the relation between `A`, `B` and `C`. 
If both evaluate to `True` the relationships "match" and the final result will be `True`.

Comment: I think this is a little different than the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to generate `mask` using only relationships between `A`, `B`, and `C`, so that `df[mask]` matches another subset of data that I've obtained using a mask from a relationship between `D` and `E`. So that something like `df[mask_ABC] == df[mask_DE]` would be `True`.

Comment: So in other words, all values from `mask` must be `True`. Or at least you want to maximize the number of `True` values. And you want to find the relationship between `D` and `E` that maximimizes the `True` values, right?

Comment: `mask` is `True`, in my example, if the realtion between `D` and `E` matches the relation between `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a set of relationships where all values of `mask` are true. But my question is how do I systematically search for these relationships. If I consider equalities, inequalities, and strict inequalities as valid relationships, that gives me 125 possibilities to consider for each pairwise relationship among `A`, `B`, and `C`. Even if I check every possibility, how can I iterate over these?

Comment: Don't make it too complicated. If `A < B` evaluates to `True`, so does `A <= B`. Given that, you can only check the partial order of those sets. What remains are 6 possibilities: `A <= B <= C`, `A <= C <= B`, `B <= A <= C`, `B <= C <= A`, and so forth